# load image after upload in asp.net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, image-uploading, partial-page-refresh

My question is image uploading , uploading and image load method are working perfect but im showing images below the upload control, after click upload button new image must be added to line.. what is the reason?

this is uploading code:

```
            DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath(@"~/Bailiffs/BailiffImages/"));
            string cukurNumber = txtCukurNumber.Text;
            int sequence = 0;
            string fileName = string.Empty;
            FileInfo[] fileInfos = directoryInfo.GetFiles(cukurNumber + "*");
            if (afuImage.HasFile)
            {
                if (fileInfos.Length != 0)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < fileInfos.Length; i++)
                    {
                        string fileNumber = fileInfos[i].Name.Substring(fileInfos[i].Name.LastIndexOf("-") + 1, fileInfos[i].Name.LastIndexOf(".") - fileInfos[i].Name.LastIndexOf("-") - 1);
                        sequence = int.Parse(fileNumber) + 1;
                    }
                    fileName = cukurNumber + "--" + sequence + ".jpg";
                }
                else
                {
                    fileName = cukurNumber + "--1.jpg";
                }
                afuImage.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(@"/Bailiffs/BailiffImages/" + fileName));
                CreateImages(); // recreates images
            }
```

thx...

Comment: Please post some code if there aren't any error message.

Comment: there is no error i just need to (refreshimages or page) show new image with the others

Comment: the <img /> element must be inside UpdatePanel

Comment: it is inside of updatepanel probably its about fileupload control i read sonewhere (i dont know where when) fileupload control just working postbacktrigger not async but im already using it postbacktrigger...

Answer (score 1):

Use ajax to call a page method which retrieves the url of the image just uploaded and shows it in an img tag. Ajax and Jquery are your tools and friends.

Comment: yes david youre right i hate javascript but i have to i guess :D

Comment: get rid of this "hate", in 2011 asp.net and JavaScript should be blended or you won't be able to deliver any smooth user experience to your customers

Comment: just downloaded 2011 , i couldnt look through it but i heard too

Comment: I meant 2011 the calendar year ( DateTime.UtcNow.Year ); not any sw version :-D